# Onchange event not working in select box

Tags: javascript, onchange

I added a `dropdownlist` using seblod extension in joomla. But the javascript is not working for this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('onload');
            document.getElementById('countrynames').addEventListener('change',function(){
                alert('Hello');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select size="1" class="inputbox select " name="countrynames" id="countrynames">
            <option selected="selected" value="">- Select an option -</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script is running before the select element exists on the page.

Comment: Note that the change event behaves differently in various browsers. Try using keyboard navigation to select an option in IE and see if it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your script to the bottom of the page - after the DOM element you're binding the listener to.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mA8NZ/)

```
<select size="1" class="inputbox select " name="countrynames" id="countrynames">
<option selected="selected" value="">- Select an option -</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('onload');
    document.getElementById('countrynames').addEventListener('change',function(){
         alert('Hello');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I just copy pasted the jsfiddle code over my code, but nothing happens while executing it. What could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You script is executing before the select element is created. here's the fix:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                alert('onload');
                document.getElementById('countrynames').addEventListener('change',function(){
                    alert('Hello');
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select size="1" class="inputbox select " name="countrynames" id="countrynames">
            <option selected="selected" value="">- Select an option -</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to put your code in a function which will be called by the `<body>` tag's `onload` method:

**Your JS script:**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function mload() {
            alert('onload');
            document.getElementById('countrynames').addEventListener('change',function()      {alert('Hello');

            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

**In your `<body>` add:**

```
<body onload="javascript: mload()">
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if this works for you.